# Cannot upload picture by explorer in Picture Library SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a very strange behaviour when I upload some pictures from the explorer to the picture library. When I copy files to the folder in picture library no problems and also no problems with rendition images as "/w" and "/t" but I have problem with the original picture, when I try to open in IE I have empty image, in explorer have an error: can't open picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted or is to large.

Explain me please, what is the reason of this behavior?

Comment: What does your ER do? Are you 100% it's because of your ER? i.e. the problem does not happen when ER is removed?

Comment: Can you post some code related to event receiver ?

Comment: @Evariste. yes, the reason is not in ER.

Answer (score 0):

That may happen when the file extension does not match its real content type (e.g. a PNG file with a .jpg extension). Internet Explorer (unlike Chrome) does check if the content it receives matches the file extension; if it doesn't, the image is not displayed.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have uploaded the same picture but with other name, and I have no result using explorer.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in http**s**://. When I open explorer via http://... problem doesn't apear.